# Satisfiability of a union of sets

Tags: satisfiability

I know this may be a very basic question but I'm new to some of these concepts and I would just like to make sure I understand the reasoning.

The question is to say whether the following statement is true or false. If it is true, establish that it is and if it is false, provide a counterexample:
If Δ and Γ are each satisfiable sets of formulae, then Δ∪Γ is a satisfiable set of formulae.

I think the answer is true but I'm having a hard time establishing why it is true.

Thanks!

Comment: Not true; consider $\Delta= \{ p \}$ and $\Gamma = \{ \lnot p \}$.

Comment: wow, I didn't even think of something so trivial as a counterexample. Thanks for the reply!